# DataFlow difference in Hadoop Standalone and Pseudodistributed mode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can someone please tell me what is the difference in dataflow of Hadoop Standalone and Pseudodistributed mode. Infact I am trying to run an example of matrix multiplication presented by John Norstad. It runs fine in hadoop standalone mode but does not work properly in pseudodistributed mode. I am unable to fix the problem so please tell me the principle difference between hadoop standalone and pseudodistributed mode which can be helpful for fixing the stated problem.Thanks

Reagrds,

WL

Comment: What error do you get in pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: it does not give any run time error but the answers of matrix multiplication are not correct in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

In standalone mode everything (namenode, datanode, tasktracker, jobtracker) is running in one JVM on one machine.  In pseudo-distributed mode, everything is running each in it's own JVM, but still on one machine. In terms of the client interface there shouldn't be any difference, but I wouldn't be surprised if the serialization requirements are more strict in pseudo-distributed mode.

My reasoning for the above is that in pseudo-distributed mode, everything must be serialized to pass data between JVMs. In standalone mode, it isn't strictly necessary for everything to be serializable (since everything is in one JVM, you have shared memory), but I don't remember if the code is written to take advantage of that fact, since that's not a normal use case for Hadoop.

EDIT: Given that you are not seeing an error, I think it sounds like a problem in the way the MapReduce job is coded.  Perhaps he relies on something like shared memory among the reducers?  If so, that would work in standalone mode but not in pseudo-distributed mode (or truly distributed mode, for that matter).

Comment: As I am not expert in this field. Can you please suggest me that what factors I need to check which shows that it is relying on shared memory?

Comment: Are there any static variables in the mapper class, the reducer class, or any custom classes that are used by them?

Comment: no there are no static variables in mapper or reducer classes. but yeah there are some global vaiables defined as static which are being used in these classes.

Comment: That's almost certainly the issue.  You may need to re-work the jobs for proper distributed operation.

Comment: but the thing is there are 4 different strategies implemented for multiplication. 2 of them works fine but 2 does not work(even for some values these 2 also work). if static variables are the problem then should not it be a problem all the time? please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, it may be a transient problem even within a single strategy.  Note at the bottom of Norstad's web page (http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html) he states "The code has been tested with Hadoop running in standalone mode. It has not been tested on an actual Hadoop cluster."

Comment: yes he stated so your vote is that its most probably the problem of static variable?

Comment: Yes.  What you are seeing sounds like a mapper or reducer that has an expectation that every single map (or reduce) task is going to run on the same JVM.  That expectation is met in standalone mode, and is not met in pseudo- or fully- distributed mode.  You need to fix the code.

Comment: infact I had compared the standalone outputs and pseudodistributed outputs.And to be precise I found out that the key.m variable is having different values. The pattern for key.m in standalone mode is 0 1 0 1 0 1....but in pseudodistributed mode its like 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0....so any suggestion that how can I fix it.

Comment: Ah, that could be a different issue.  Input with a single mapper is predictably ordered.  Input with multiple mappers is not predictably ordered (and mappers must not rely on ordered input).

Comment: I found out that it works all good with sparse matrices. Problem is only with dense matrices so you would still think it can be same problem of shared memory?

Comment: Also in description of strategy 1 pseudocode its written "These definitions for the sorting order and partitioner guarantee that each reducer R[ib,kb,jb] receives the data it needs for blocks A[ib,kb] and B[kb,jb], with the data for the A block immediately preceding the data for the B block. " i believe problem is here as the sequence of A and B block data is not correct. and it all depends on key.m.(0 for A and 1 for B). so it should be like 0 1 0 1(A B A B A B) but its like 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 (A B B A A B B A A)as mentioned before.